# What is " the two-parameter family of vectors"

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors

Please I've just started reading "Partial Differential Equations: Modeling, Analysis, Computation" and I found a definition which I can't understand. In page 13 "The independent variables x and t and the dependent variable u constitute a two-parameter family of vectors (x, t, u)^T"

I expect because we have x,t and u so we have 3 parameters not 2.

Also, what does the superscript "T" mean?

You can find this page [here](https://books.google.be/books?id=eNoEWxLes38C&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22two%20parameter%20family%20of%20vectors%22&source=bl&ots=ex__6fZcXE&sig=DBWD2WMa0RJ2V1FjQZufVodaD6g&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMx7mqtazJAhVC0RoKHZQvBsUQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22two%20parameter%20family%20of%20vectors%22&f=false)

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u is a given function of x and t, so the triplet (x,t,u) is really (x,t,u(x,t)) which leaves two degrees of freedom, namely, x and t.

The capital T means "transpose": exchanging rows and columns of a matrix. In this case it means re-interpreting (x,t,u) as a column of three numbers rather than a horizontal row. Many authors prefer to express the coordinates of a three-dimensional vector as a column.

Comment: Thank you so much for that clarification